# Terraform on GCP: How to whitelist my cluster nodes for RDS

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, amazon-rds, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster and an RDS configured in terraform, now i want to whitelist the node-IPs for the RDS. Is there a way to somehow access the node-pool instances from the cluster-config? What i basically want for the RDS config is something like

```
    ip_configuration {

      dynamic "authorized_networks" {
        for_each = google_container_cluster.data_lake.network
        iterator = node
        content {
          name = node.network.ip
          value = node.network.ip
        }
      }
    }
```

But from what i see there seems to be no way to get a list of the nodes/the-IPs..
I tried

```
    ip_configuration {
      authorized_networks {
        value = google_container_cluster.my_cluster.cluster_ipv4_cidr
      }
    }
```

which resulted in `Non-routable or private authorized network (10.80.0.0/14).., invalid` so it looks like this only works with public IPs. Or i have to setup a separate VPC for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you to first set up the **NAT gateway** in front of the **GKE** so that you can manage your all outgoing traffic from a single **egress** point.

You can use this terraform to create & setup the NAT gateway : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/latest/examples/gke-nat-gateway

Module source code : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/v1.2.3/examples/gke-nat-gateway

Using **NAT gateway** your all Nodes traffic will be going out of single IP and you can whitelist this `single IP` into the `RDS`.

Since **RDS** is in **AWS** service, VPC peering is not possible otherwise if are using the GCP SQL that would also one option.